# Save data sent by the client to the server in a REST API

Tags: python, rest, flask

My knowledge of RESTful services is almost 0 and I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of days now.

What i'm trying to achieve is having a client communicating with other clients through REST, modifying a specific variable saved in the api file so that, later on, another client can request for that variable which has been changed.

Something akin to this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
aString = ""

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "<h1>THE WORST REST API</h1>"

@app.route("/write")
def write():
    aString = "chop"
    return home()

@app.route("/read")
def read():
    return aString
```

- The client calls /read, receives ""
- The client calls /write, aString changes into "chop"
- Another client calls /read, receives "chop"

Now this isn't possible with this code (though I'm not sure why, I guess the reason is that every REST request reloads the API so changes done to aString are lost immediately) however I need some way to achieve this.

As I said, I am absolutely ignorant when it comes to this stuff, but I absolutely have to make the 2 clients communicate using this string one way or another, while keeping things as simple as possible.

Also, I'm a tad bit restrained when it comes to tools I can download/install due to the fact I'm coding in a work environment and I can't download too much stuff just to make this small thing work. Any solution is appreciated as long as all the libraries/modules I need can simply be retrieved using "pip install".

Thanks a lot to any of you who's willing to answer!

Comment: I would suspect that `aString` is redefined in your `write` method. You are not writing to the global variable but create a new local one that "shadows" the global one. Try declaring `global aString` in the function before writing to it.

Comment: @tilman151 that solved it! Thanks a lot. I completely forgot about the usage of global (I started programming in Python in the past few months and I never had to use that keyword before so it skipped my mind)

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, HTTP is stateless. Neither the server nor the client save state between requests per default.

That's why your `aString` is gone after the first request.

You have several options:

- either store the string in a text file or a database
- make use of sessions (e.g. save a cookie or with similar techniques)

What way you choose depends on your requirements.

Comment: The first option is a no go: I'm doing this specifically to avoid making the REST server connect to the database while text files would not suit this project at all (don't really know why I can't use the database, it's part of the project requirements although it would've saved me a lot of time and headache). As for the session option, I was under the impression that changes done in a session persist for that session only, so if I change aString in a client-session, the other clients will not see it. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: There seems to be a (non recommended way) to store the data on the `app` object, but beware, when you run several instances of your app (as you usually do), this won't work out.